# NODE JS Неверное имя у файла с русским именем при загрузке с помощью Multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

Я пытаюсь загрузить файл с русским именем с помощью [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) и Express JS

Файл загружается на сервер, но имя становится не читаемым.

Например:

Оригинальное имя: Глоссарий.docx

Имя после загрузки:

```
    "files": [
        {
            "filename":";>AA0@89.docx",
            "path": "shared\\storage\\attachments\\files_1633962007580.docx"
        }
    ],
```

Как сохранить оригинальное имя файла

Пробовал по разному отправлять запросы через `Postman`, думал проблема в нем либо в заголовках также использовал `cURL`, но результат остался прежним.

Comment: Sorry, this part of SO is for questions in Russian. Please, use stackoverflow.com for questions in English or translate your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй следующее:

```
file.originalname = Buffer.from(file.originalname, 'latin1').toString('utf8')
```

Более подробный код ниже:

```
const storageConfig = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req, file, cb) =>{
    cb(null, "uploads");
},
filename: (req, file, cb) =>{
    file.originalname = Buffer.from(file.originalname, 'latin1').toString('utf8')
    cb(null, file.originalname);
}
```

Ответ нашел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72909624/multer-corrupts-utf8-filename-when-uploading-files).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что наиболее рациональный вариант решения - передавать имена файлов с русскими буквами в виде массива `JSON` в отдельном поле `form-data`.

Например вот так:

```
["Тестовый файл.jpg", "Test File 2.png"]
```

А затем по индексу соотносить массив с файлами и массив с оригинальными именами.